# IonInput fill outline property

Tags: javascript, vue.js, ionic-framework, ionic-vue, ionic7

I am having trouble implementing IonInput in outline style.
I need to point out that the outline appears for a while but then disappears for good. I also need to mention I am not using it inside of IonItem

```
`<ion-input
 label="Outline input"
 label-placement="stacked"
 fill="outline"
 color="black"
 placeholder="Enter text"
</ion-input>`
```

Fill property does not work both for solid and outline variants

I tried to check if all the Ionic stylesheets are properly connected, I also tried to put it inside of IonItem and remove it. None of these helped, just like reloading the app.